# javax.validation.constraints.Email in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, email-validation

I have a bean with this validation:

```
@Email(message = "Email is not valid", regexp="{(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])}")
@NotEmpty(message = "Email cannot be empty")
private String email;
```

when the email is empty the message is fine, but when I enter this text

```
perisava.util.Random@1d7f0036
```

no error is shown

Comment: can you confirm that you get `ConstraintViolationException`?

Comment: No, I don't get nothing :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`javax.validation.constraints.Email` annotation depends on `Jakarta Bean Validation providers` for validation. Hibernate Validator is the only compliant validator for this.
By default hibernate vaildator matches the email to regex `.*` unless you provide the regex yourself. Hibernate email validator source code is [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/EmailValidator.java?source=cc).

One solution is to provide your own email regex

```
@Email(message = "Email is not valid", regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$")
@NotEmpty(message = "Email cannot be empty")
private String email;
```

The official standard is RFC 5322. But it does not cover all cases for modern emails. You can find more solutions [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-email-validation-regex#regular-expression-by-rfc-5322-for-email-validation). Even then regex would be up to you to decide.

Comment: I've tried with this error: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])}
 at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:2010)

Comment: I have tried the solution and it worked for me :( . I am adding my solution. I am using java 8 with spring boot 2.3.4

Comment: I tried `perisava.util.Random@1d7f0036.com`, but it failed. This could be a valid email address.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solved by viewing the source code. **@Email** annotation has an attribute **regexp()**, the default is'.*'. And it matches the characters you enter, you can write your own regular expression
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The regex in the accepted answer is hard to read and did not work for the use-case i was testing. Here's another regex that you can use:

```
private static final Pattern EMAIL = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

public static boolean isEmail(String s) {
    return EMAIL.matcher(s).matches();
}
```

It is simpler and it works well.