# How to validate the annotation @Email?

Tags: java, spring-boot

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Register {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Email
    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

If the value of `getEmail()` is not an email address, I get this error:

> ERROR 17124 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
> commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
> transaction] with root cause
>
> javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for
> classes [*] during
> persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of
> constraint violations:[
> ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must be a well-formed
> email address', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class
> com.dynamicquatation.dq.components.register.Register,
> messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Email.message}'}

How can I validate that field? I tried it with `if (data.getEmail() != null) {...}` but I still get the same error.

This is another way how I tried to catch the error:

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class RegisterController {
    private final RegisterService registerService;

    public RegisterController(RegisterService registerService) {
        this.registerService = registerService;
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "register")
    Map<String, Object> register(@RequestBody Register data, MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
        return registerService.registerUser(data, exception);
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class RegisterService {
    public Map<String, Object> registerUser(Register data, MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();

        // Validate email
        System.out.println(exception.getFieldError("email"));
```

It gives me that error:

> Controller
> [com.dynamicquatation.dq.components.register.RegisterController]
>
> Method [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>
> com.dynamicquatation.dq.components.register.RegisterController.register(com.dynamicquatation.dq.components.register.Register,org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException)]
> with argument values:
>
> [0]
> [type=com.dynamicquatation.dq.components.register.Register]
> [value=com.dynamicquatation.dq.components.register.Register@3f303f1a],
>
> [1] [type=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult]
> [value=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0
> errors] ] with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Comment: You need to pass something looking as email. E.g. foo@bar.com

Comment: @PetrAleksandrov I know. The point is that I want to figure out if the value is email or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Alex by using `@RequestBody @Valid Register data`. But if you also want to show the error message, you will need to work with `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. Instead of using it in controller or service, you can use it in a class with a `@ControllerAdvice` annotation.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            errors.put(((FieldError) error).getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
            response.put("errors", errors);
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

That should respond:

```json
{
    "errors": {
        "email": "must be a well-formed email address"
    }
}
```

If you want a custom error message, you can use

```java
@Email(message = "Email is not valid")
```

Answer (score 1):

When receive the body, you have to call `@Valid` on it

```
@RequestBody @Valid Register data
```

though in your example it's on an entity class, which from a functionality POV will work, but it's not a pattern you'd want if the project gets more complex.

Comment: I tried the same with `Map<String, Object> register(@RequestBody @Valid Register data, MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {` but I still get the same error.

Comment: just to be sure, you used `@Valid` not `@Validated` right?

Comment: Yes, I used `@Valid` in Controller.

Comment: Can you also try to add @NotBlank under @Email? Also how do you test it?

Comment: I am testing it with Postman and the object that I pass is `{"email": "test"}`. But wait, I have removed `MethodArgumentNotValidException exception` from the Controller. So now it's just `Map<String, Object> register(@RequestBody @Valid Register data) {`. Should that be enough? If so, how do I do the validation in my service class then?

Comment: The @Valid annotation does that for you, that's its purpose. It checks for every validation annotation in the annotated class. You don't have to do anything manually

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65371615/3018285

Comment: Ok, I see. The error is gone now. But I still want to figure out if the value is an email or not. If I use `server.error.include-binding-errors=always`, then the client gets an object that contains `"defaultMessage": "must be a well-formed email address",`.  How do I output this message?

Comment: You can create a handler for the MethodArgumentNotValidException in ControllerAdvice class, and the exception will let you know what parameter was the culprit